# Atomic increment with inline assembly

Tags: c, inline

I get this error, when I try to atomically increment number. (Yes, I have to do it with inline assembly and command xaddl, and not fetch_and_add etc.)

```
tslock.c:23:3: error: matching constraint references invalid operand number
   : "cc", "memory");
   ^
tslock.c:20:2: error: matching constraint references invalid operand number
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
  ^
```

```
void atomicIncrement(int number){
    int one = 1;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "lock xaddl %1, %0;"        
        :: "0"(number),  "m"(one)
        : "cc", "memory");

    printf("new value = %d\n", number);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a number as a constraint (the string next to the operand), it means "put this operand in the same location as the one with this number".

So `"0"(number)` means that `number` goes in the same location as operand 0. But in this case, `number` **is** operand 0, so that doesn't actually tell the compiler where to put it.

You need to use a different constraint for `number` - for example "r" if it should be in a register or "m" if it should be in memory.

Comment: Thanks :)

I thought "0" was a constraint for read-write ..

I Have another queston though, 

tslock.c:21: Error: too many memory references for `xadd'


Do you have an idea for this one? :c

Comment: @NikolayMladenov Now that's an assembly question and not a C one. But if you look up some documentation for XADD, you'll see that the first operand must be a register, and the second one can be a register or a memory location.